# Limit text length in vue-Multiselect

Tags: javascript, vue.js, tailwind-css, vue-multiselect

I have used the 'Single Select' Object from the 'vue-MultiSelect' package for 'search select' in my project. The options I have in the select list are too lengthy (as they are site addresses/urls) and they flow over the input box size and destroy the UI. I may need to set up a character limit for populating the value which may help to keep the UI intact. Which class I can use to limit the length of the text that populate? Or any better alternatives?

For Normal select list, We can set the data-limit like data-limit ="37" to limit the text length.

```
<select
  v-model="filter.url_name"
  class="w-4/6 relative truncate overflow-hidden form-select pr-10 appearance-none "
  aria-label="Default select example">
  <option
    class="absolute w-4/6 truncate overflow-hidden right-0"
    data-limit="37"
    :value="item"
    v-for="(item, index) in requiredUrlsFiltersData"
    :key="index"
  >
    {{ item }}
  </option>
</select>
```

For vue-multi select, I have tried the same way and tried to pass it inside a method
like this

```
@input="siteSelected(filter.url_name, 37, filter.url_name.length)"
```

and return the value

```
siteSelected(str, max, len) {  
  return len > max ? str.substring(0, 37) : str;
},
```

Both didn't work.

```
<multiselect
  v-model="filter.url_name"
  :options="requiredUrlsFiltersData"
  placeholder="select a url"
  class="max-w-sm"
  data-limit="37"
  :rules="maxlength"
  @input="siteSelected(filter.url_name, 37, filter.url_name.length)"
  :show-labels="false"   
>
</multiselect>
```